# averiguar que imagen ha sido asignado a objeto imagen

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2019

Me gustaría saber si hay alguna manera de averigüar que imagen se ha asignado a un objeto imagen en WPF por codigo c#.
Después de hacer esto por ejemplo:

```
Ruta= System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\..\\..\\..\\";
imagen9.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(Ruta + "cruz.png", UriKind.Absolute));
```

¿Cómo puedo averigüar más adelante en el programa, que imágen se le asignó?
Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que podrías probar con el siguiente código..

```
BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
bitmapImage.BeginInit();
bitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri("http://localhost/_DSC0231.JPG");
bitmapImage.EndInit();

myImage.Source = bitmapImage;

var aux = (BitmapImage)this.myImage.Source;
myImageName.Text = aux.UriSource.AbsoluteUri;
```

Con esto, he podido conocer qué archivo tengo en la imagen (myImage).

Espero te ayude, sino... Escríbeme y lo vemos,
Un saludo!

Comment: Buenas Rubén, gracias por la ayuda, así podría conseguir un string de la dirección completa y buscar el nombre del fichero, pero una pregunta...¿Que es el objeto myImageName?

Comment: Estupendo! myImageName es un TextBox que he usado para visualizar el uri, realmente podría haber sido una variable de tipo string para usar la cadena de alguna otra manera.. Con "aux.UriSource.LocalPath" podrías obtener el nombre del archivo, en mi ejemplo, sería así: "/_DSC0231.JPG"
Si no necesitas nada más, por favor, marca la respuesta como aceptada
Un saludo!

Comment: Si lo que deseas es la imagen (no la ruta) podrías usar directamente la variable aux, esto es la imagen digitalizada.